# Можно ли весь код поместить в один lock?

Tags: c#

```
public class Worker
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ManualResetEventSlim> _etpIdToReadyEventSlim = new();
    private readonly DefaultRtsMarketWaiterSettings _settings = new();

    public Task WaitProcedureAsync(Procedure procedure,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ManualResetEventSlim manualResetEventSlim;
        
        lock (_etpIdToReadyEventSlim)
        {
            if (!_etpIdToReadyEventSlim.TryGetValue(procedure.EtpId,
                    out manualResetEventSlim))
            {
                manualResetEventSlim = new ManualResetEventSlim();
                
                _etpIdToReadyEventSlim.Add(procedure.EtpId, manualResetEventSlim);
                
                Task.Run(() => DoWaitAsync(procedure.EtpId,
                        cancellationToken),
                    cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        manualResetEventSlim.Wait(cancellationToken);

        lock (_etpIdToReadyEventSlim)
        {
            if (_etpIdToReadyEventSlim.Remove(procedure.EtpId))
            {
                manualResetEventSlim.Dispose();
            }   
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task DoWaitAsync(string etpId,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

        DateTime startsAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

        try
        {
            while (DateTime.UtcNow - startsAtUtc < _settings.MaxWaitingTimeSpan)
            {
                try
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    Console.WriteLine($"Id работы: {id}");

                    await Task.Delay(_settings.BetweenChecksDelay,
                        cancellationToken);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //Ignore
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _etpIdToReadyEventSlim[etpId].Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли всё поместить в один lock?

Comment: `Task.Run` возвращает `Task`, вы его никак не используете и нигде не ожидаете. Это ошибка и имеет такие же проблемы как использование `async void`. Нет никакого смысла выделять отдельный поток под и без того асинхронный метод, лишняя работа. Что метод возвращает `Task`, что `Task.Run` делает то же самое. А что этот код делает то, и зачем здесь `lock` вообще?

Comment: И вообще под блокировку обычно выделяют обычно банальный приватный `object`, блокировать через использование сложных объектов - способ рано или поздно выстрелить себе в ногу. Явно нужно описание задачи, она наверняка решается гораздо проще, без этой мешанины совершенно разных концепций.

Comment: Этот код выполняет парсинг интернет ресурса. Метод WaitProcedureAsync вызывается из разных мет приложения я может быть такое, что может быть несколько одинаковых Procedure. Мне нужно не допустить, чтобы произошёл запуск DoWaitAsync для двух одинаковых процедур. Lock служит для синхронизации к разделяемому ресурсу, которым является словарь. После того как завершится метод DoWaitAsync мы должны удалить значение из словаря

Comment: CrazyElf, я своему коллеге так же говорю, на что я слышу ответ, что тут обеспечивается доступ к одному разделяемому ресурсу и можно в качестве объекта заглушки использовать словарь

Comment: "Мне нужно не допустить, чтобы произошёл запуск `DoWaitAsync` для двух одинаковых процедур." - так а что в этом случае должно произойти в точности? Вторая процедура не должна запуститься вообще или вторая процедура должна дождаться, пока закончится первая и тогда всё же запуститься? В первом случае насколько я понимаю вместо всей этой катавасии достаточно было бы использовать `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: @CrazyElf я использовал ConcurentDict. Я использовал его метод GetOrAdd, но так как метод GetOrAdd не атомарный я его лочил, и подумал зачем мне ConcurentDict если я его всё-равно добавляю в lock. 

Процедура, которая есть в словаре, не должна быть запущена

Comment: Используйте `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ManualResetEventSlim>` и не надо никаких локов вообще. _GetOrAdd не атомарный_ - вы серьезно? Все методы `ConcurrentDictionary` являются потокобезопасными, атомарность не имеет значения здесь вообще.